# "Locking" focus within a Frame control

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-runtime, focus, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to make my UWP app play nice with xbox controllers, and am running into the following issue:

As a system for modal windows, I've got a `Frame` control in the foreground of my MainPage, and a mask *behind* the frame that acts as a dismiss layer (clicking on it closes the frame). The UI stack looks like this:

```
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="content"></Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="LightDismiss" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <Frame x:Name="SubFrame" Visibility="Collapsed" MaxWidth="500" MaxHeight="500" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I then have a `SubFrameNavigator()`that will navigate the subframe to the specified page, and animate the LightDismiss layer.

The issue is that XY navigation with a gamepad completely, and logically, ignores the dismiss layer making it possible to move focus from within the frame to controls in the grid behind it. How can I "lock" focus *within* the Frame, so that it's impossible to move focus outside of it?

I've tried setting `XYFocusKeyboardNavigationMode` to `Disabled` on the grid containing the app's content, but it doesn't seem to change anything. I've also tried fiddling with the `FocusEngagement` related properties, but I've had no success either.

Comment: Could you please provide the detailed XAML layout code?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I updated the post with a simplified version of the XAML layout code.

Comment: Wow, your code was so simple. I could not use it to reproduce your issue. Please provide a [mcve] :).